# mysql insert clause gives #1064 error

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table **school**

```
id       dob         name      surname
1      03.04.2011     jj
2      14.07.1999     na
..     ............   ..
```

I have many rows of data in the above table. Now what I want to do is; fill the **surname** column using an insert clause as follows

```
INSERT INTO `school` (surname) VALUES
('highvision'),
('oceanof'),
('malindimetho'),
('tahdhibprima'),
('stpatricks'),
...............
('stpatricks');
```

**note:** the number of rows I am inserting equals the number of rows in my table

On using the above INSERT statement I get the following error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line ..
```

How can I insert the rows?

Comment: Is `.........` really part of your code?

Comment: Assuming that `..............` is something which you want to show that there are many rows which you want to insert in your table. There is nothing wrong in your query which you have pasted here. So I guess you have a quotes `'` missing somewhere for a value in your query. Also do check that the column `surname` has enough length to hold the data which you are giving.

Comment: Dear, but if your table is already fill, and you want fill surname field, please use UPDATE.

Comment: @Itay no I used the dots to show that there are other many rows I didn't include

Comment: @RahulTripathi  there seems to be no problem with quotes

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `INSERT` to **fill** the table.

You can use the following:

```
UPDATE `school` SET `surname` = 'highvision' WHERE `id` = '1'
```

Comment: how do I use update for many rows. I thought update works on a single row.

Comment: I think it does not have a easy way to do so. If this operation wont need to run many time in future. you can use Excel to generate your sql script.